# meson add existing dll as dependency

Tags: c++, windows, dll, meson-build

I want to add a dll as dependency to my own project under Windows.
I tried following:

```
lept_include = include_directories('../libs/tesseract')
lept_lib = '/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract/liblept-5.dll'
lept_dep = declare_dependency(link_with:lept_lib, include_directories:lept_include)

executable('test1', 'main.cpp', dependencies: [boost_dep, lept_dep])
```

but got this error:

```
..\meson.build:25:0: ERROR: '/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract/liblept-5.dll' is not a target.
```

I also tried this but dit not work either:

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
lib_l1 = cc.find_library('liblept-5.dll',  dirs : ['/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract'])
lib_l2 = cc.find_library('liblept-5',  dirs : ['/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract'])
lib_l3 = cc.find_library('lept-5.dll',  dirs : ['/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract'])
lib_l4 = cc.find_library('lept-5',  dirs : ['/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract'])
```

How can I achieve this?
thanks

Comment: I think you need to declare a custom_target() or a shared_library() with that include.
Have a look at these two projects: https://github.com/jmgao/dhc/blob/050973600ef14d6289921cde1a4b218c20cac72d/meson.build
and 
https://github.com/SveSop/nvapi_standalone/blob/e7b97ec63f1e76d4f365b29f96c6bcbb9c782baa/dlls/nvapi/meson.build

Comment: shared_library is building a library which is not the use case. custom_target did not lead to success, at least not the way i used it...
Amazingly `lib_l4 = cc.find_library('lept-5',  dirs : ['/cygdrive/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract'])` is working now. At first I was using MSYS for windows, now I tried CYGWIN and the lib was found.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly `lib_l4 = cc.find_library('lept-5',  dirs : ['/cygdrive/g/programming/meson/libs/tesseract'])` is working now. At first I was using MSYS for windows, now I tried CYGWIN and the lib was found.